# Slide multiple divs from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my divs to have a sliding effect from right to left, what should I change in CSS and JS files?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
$('#slider-container').animate({scrollRight:"-="-slideW}, 600);
```

This is the original code with slide effect from left to right.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var slideW = $('#slider-container').width();
    $('.slide').click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#slider-container').animate({scrollLeft:"+="+slideW}, 600);
        if($('#slider-container').next()==0){
            $('#slider-container').first().animate({scrollLeft:"+="+slideW}, 600);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#slider-container{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#cf5;
    width:100%;
    height:850px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#slider-container div{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:-4px;
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align:top;
    *display:inline;
    background:#eee;
    width:100%;
    height:850px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider-container">
        <div class="slide active"><p>This is desktop 1</p></div>
        <div class="slide">This is desktop 2</div>
        <div class="slide">This is desktop 3</div>
        <div class="slide">This is desktop 4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so good at javascript right now, but you can always create the same effect with CSS. You can make a keyframe and add animation to the class of the elements you want to animate.

For Example:

```
@keyframes moveInLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
    80% {
        transform: translateX(10px); 
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0); 
    }
}
```

Play around with the px and you will most definitely have the same result, you can also add opacities to certain percentage values to create and even cooler effect.
Hope this helped a bit

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct in switching "+=" to "-=" but you need to use scrollLeft and if you are on the first slide there is no "left" to go to.

It's not an extremely elegant solution but I added some navigation controls and another function to handle left and right scrolling.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
                var slideW = $('#slider-container').width();
                $('#right').click(function( e ){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#slider-container').animate({scrollLeft:"+="+slideW}, 600);
                        if($('#slider-container').next()==0){
                            $('#slider-container').first().animate({scrollLeft:"+="+slideW}, 600);
                        }  
                });

                $('#left').click(function( e ){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#slider-container').animate({scrollLeft:"-="+slideW}, 600);
                    if($('#slider-container').next()==0){
                        $('#slider-container').first().animate({scrollLeft:"+="+slideW}, 600);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #slider-container{
                position:relative;
                overflow:hidden;
                margin:0 auto;
                background:#cf5;
                width:100%;
                height:150px;
                white-space:nowrap;
            }

            #slider-container div{
                position:relative;
                display:inline-block;
                margin-right:-4px;
                white-space:normal;
                vertical-align:top;
                *display:inline;
                background:#eee;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }

            .controls div {
                display: inline-block;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slider-container">
            <div class="slide active"><p>This is desktop 1</p></div>
            <div class="slide">This is desktop 2</div>
            <div class="slide">This is desktop 3</div>
            <div class="slide">This is desktop 4</div>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <div id="left"><<<</div>
            <div id="right">>>></div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```